# How to calculate collision flags in 2D javafx game

Tags: java, javafx, 2d

I have recently begun working on a 2D arcade game engine. It is written in java and uses javafx instead of swing. Currently I have been able to simulate gravity for objects and move them around. I want to add collisions into my engine. An example of this is:

A box(object A) is sliding due east towards a box(object B). When object A collides with Object B I want to detect that that Object A's east side hit something.

I have been trying to get this to work for days now. Currently my code works some of the times. It DOESN'T work well with horizontal collisions.

My method to detect what side the of the object collided.

```
public Rectangle2D getBoundary() {
    return new Rectangle2D(getX(), getY(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
}

public CollisionFlag getCollisionFlag(ArrayList<GameObject> objects) {
    for (GameObject object : objects) {
        if (object.getBoundary().intersects(this.getBoundary())) {
            if (this.getBoundary().getMaxY() > object.getBoundary().getMaxY()) {
                // ball under object, means my ball getY() is in the object
                if (this.getX() < object.getX()
                        || (this.getX() >= object.getX() && this.getX() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxX())) {
                    // ball is somewhere inside objects x
                    return CollisionFlag.NORTH;
                }
            } else if (this.getY() < object.getY()) {
                // ball above object, means my ball getMaxY() is in object
                if (this.getX() < object.getX()
                        || (this.getX() >= object.getX() && this.getX() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxX())) {
                    return CollisionFlag.SOUTH;
                }
            } else if (this.getX() < object.getX()) {
                // ball to the left of object, means my ball getMaxX() is in
                // object
                if (this.getY() < object.getY()
                        || (this.getY() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxY() && this.getY() >= object.getY())) {
                    return CollisionFlag.EAST;
                }
            } else if (this.getBoundary().getMaxX() > object.getBoundary().getMaxX()) {
                // ball to the right of object, means my ball getX() is in
                // object
                if (this.getY() < object.getY()
                        || (this.getY() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxY() && this.getY() >= object.getY())) {
                    return CollisionFlag.WEST;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return CollisionFlag.NONE;
}
```

Here is my full GameObject class.

```
    package org.bautista.ag.api.objects;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.bautista.ag.api.GameEngine;
import org.bautista.ag.api.locatable.CollisionFlag;
import org.bautista.ag.api.locatable.Position;

import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public abstract class GameObject extends ImageView {

    private final Image image;
    private final boolean movable;
    private double xVelocity;
    private double yVelocity;
    private Position position;

    public GameObject(final Image image, final Position position, final boolean movable) {
        super(image);
        this.image = image;
        this.movable = movable;
        this.position = position;
        reposition(position);
    }

    public Rectangle2D getBoundary() {
        return new Rectangle2D(getX(), getY(), image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }

    public CollisionFlag getCollisionFlag(ArrayList<GameObject> objects) {
        for (GameObject object : objects) {
            if (object.getBoundary().intersects(this.getBoundary())) {
                if (this.getBoundary().getMaxY() > object.getBoundary().getMaxY()) {
                    // ball under object, means my ball getY() is in the object
                    if (this.getX() < object.getX()
                            || (this.getX() >= object.getX() && this.getX() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxX())) {
                        // ball is somewhere inside objects x
                        return CollisionFlag.NORTH;
                    }
                } else if (this.getY() < object.getY()) {
                    // ball above object, means my ball getMaxY() is in object
                    if (this.getX() < object.getX()
                            || (this.getX() >= object.getX() && this.getX() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxX())) {
                        return CollisionFlag.SOUTH;
                    }
                } else if (this.getX() < object.getX()) {
                    // ball to the left of object, means my ball getMaxX() is in
                    // object
                    if (this.getY() < object.getY()
                            || (this.getY() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxY() && this.getY() >= object.getY())) {
                        return CollisionFlag.EAST;
                    }
                } else if (this.getBoundary().getMaxX() > object.getBoundary().getMaxX()) {
                    // ball to the right of object, means my ball getX() is in
                    // object
                    if (this.getY() < object.getY()
                            || (this.getY() <= object.getBoundary().getMaxY() && this.getY() >= object.getY())) {
                        return CollisionFlag.WEST;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return CollisionFlag.NONE;
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public double getXVelocity() {
        return xVelocity;
    }

    public double getYVelocity() {
        return yVelocity;
    }

    public boolean intersects(final GameObject gameObject) {
        return gameObject.getBoundary().intersects(getBoundary())
                && (gameObject.getPosition().getZ() == getPosition().getZ());
    }

    public boolean isElevated() {
        return getBoundary().getMaxY() < GameEngine.getInstance().getBackground().getHeight();
    }

    public boolean isMovable() {
        return movable;
    }

    public boolean isMoving() {
        return xVelocity != 0 || yVelocity != 0;
    }

    public void reposition(final double x, final double y, final double z) {
        reposition(new Position(x, y, z));
    }

    public void reposition(final Position position) {
        this.position = position;
        setX(position.getX());
        setY(position.getY());
    }

    public void setXVelocity(final double xVelocity) {
        this.xVelocity = xVelocity;
    }

    public void setYVelocity(final double yVelocity) {
        this.yVelocity = yVelocity;
    }

    public void update() {
        updateLocation();
    }

    private void updateLocation() {
        if (movable) {
            reposition((getX() + xVelocity), (getY() - yVelocity), position.getZ());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems to be conceptually incomplete; the comments talk about "ball", but all I see is comparisons of coordinates implying rectangular shape only. Also, this will not handle corner collisions by design - top and bottom borders are given preferential treatment (e.g. imagine two rectangles touching just at their corners).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was using a game object with a ball picture on it as the object that was colliding with others.